# How to copy recursively files with multiple specific extensions in bash

Tags: bash, cp

I want to copy all files with specific extensions recursively in bash.

****editing****

I've written the full script. I have list of names in a csv file, I'm iterating through each name in that list, then creating a directory with that same name somewhere else, then I'm searching in my source directory for the directory with that name, inside it there are few files with endings of `xlsx,tsv,html,gz` and I'm trying to copy all of them into the newly created directory.

```
sample_list_filepath=/home/lists/papers
destination_path=/home/ds/samples
source_directories_path=/home/papers_final/new

cat $sample_list_filepath/sample_list.csv | while read line
 do
    echo $line
    cd $source_directories_path/$line
    cp -r *.{tsv,xlsx,html,gz} $source_directories_path/$line $destination_path

done
```

This works, but it copies all the files there, with no discrimination for specific extension.

What is the problem?

Comment: What's this for? `$source_directories_path/$line`

Comment: What do you mean by "recursively". Your command will only be recursive if at least one source argument is a directory

Comment: I've edited it to make it clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to solve your problem is to use `find` and `regex` :

```
find src/ -regex '.*\.\(tsv\|xlsx\|gz\|html\)$' -exec cp {} dest/ \;
```

`find` look recursively in the directory you specify (in my example it's src/), allows you to filter with `-regex` and to apply a command for matching results with `-exec`

For the regex part :

```
.*\.
```

will take the name of the file and the dot before extension,

```
\(tsv\|xlsx\|gz\|html\)$
```

verify the extension with those you want.

The exec block is what you do with files you got from regex

```
-exec cp {} dest/ \;
```

In this case, you copy what you got (`{}` meaning) to the destination directory.

Comment: That works perfectly after I created a destination directory. Thanks!